# How to return value from For loop in python?

Tags: python, function, for-loop, dictionary, return

I have a function :

```
 def getvalues():
       global avalue
       global bvalue
       dictt = getresults()
       for key , value in dictt.iteritems():
            avalue = key
            bvalue = dictt[key]
            print avalue , bvalue
```

This prints the value of avalue , bvalue
Output:

```
C123 1
C245 2
C456 2
C565 3
C654 1
```

but , returning the values outside for loop doesn't iterate over.Like this:

```
 def getvalues():
       global avalue
       global bvalue
       dictt = getresults()
       for key , value in dictt.iteritems():
            avalue = key
            bvalue = dictt[key]
       return avalue , bvalue
```

I need avalue , bvalue to be used outside this function.How can this be done??
If i use return i get the output as

```
C654 1
```

I need the same output of above with all avalue , bvalue that i can use in other function

Comment: You can use `list` to append say `avalue = [], bvalue= []` and use like `avalue.append(key) , bvalue.append(getvalues[key])` return these and you can iterate over them use outside function

Comment: Not sure what you want, but this could be a case for a [generator with `yield`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) (third code sample).

Comment: Your code makes little sense; it calls itself until Python runs out of stack, and it seems to confuse the name of the function with the name of the dictionary. Please post code that actually runs and does what you say it does.

Comment: corrected the sample code differentiating function name and dictionary name

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
def getvalues():
    values = []
    dictt = getvalues()
    for key , value in getvalues.iteritems():
         values.append((key, getvalues[key])) 
    return values
```

Comment: append() takes only one argument

Comment: he is appending a tuple.  that is one argument.  Notice how it's values.append( (key, getvalues[key]) ).  So you end up with a list of tuples. Each item in that list is a tuple with two values.  Unless this was later added in the edit, not sure if You noticed it.